# Clang static analyzer output in xml format

Tags: objective-c, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer, cppcheck

Is it possible to get output in XML format from Clang scan-build analyzer? Currently following command generates output in html format to view in webbrowser.

```
scan-build xcodebuild -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator
```

CppCheck on windows generate output in XML format. I need to parse result into same format as CppCheck. But I can't use cppCheck on MACOS. What I am trying to achieve is feed results into Sonar C++ Plugin so that I can create dashboard(continous integration) report of ObjectiveC project. Sonar C++ plugin uses CppCheck to static analyze the code.

Any input will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Running `scan-build --help` shows:

```
-plist         - By default the output of scan-build is a set of HTML files.
                 This option outputs the results as a set of .plist files.
```

Comment: Thanks. It creates multiple .plist files per each class. For example in /tmp/scan-build-dir/ I can see lot of .plist files.Would it be  possible to get just one .plist file with all static analysis results?

Comment: `scan-build` is just a perl script, IIRC.  You should be able to modify it without too much effort.

Comment: Modifying scripts installed via package management systems is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

By default clang static analyzer outputs in xml format. `scan-build` want clang static analyzer to output in html and parses the html outputs to generate a summary of all the errors found by the static-anlayzer during the build process.

If you see the scan-build script, there is a `PostProcess` function when the output format is `html`. `scan-build` does not postprocess the `plist` files as of now. If you are familiar with XML you should be able to parse the XML (`.plist`) files and do a post processing to generate a summary.